# Adding buttons to WPF from ObservableCollection using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to add buttons to UserControl. I have to follow MVVM pattern. I have created a class, DeviceButton, with different set/gets and a constructor. In a viewmodel, used as datacontext, is the ObservableCollection and a get-method for the collection. I have bound the collection to a ItemsControl source and tried to add a template. I guess I'm missing something 'cause the buttons won't load.

The UserControl is added into a tab (using [dragablz](http://dragablz.net/)) which as well is a part of a ObservableCollection, also added at run time (this is working just fine). The idea is, that the tab has a list of buttons that has to be created at run time, where the list is fetched from a web service - so the buttons has to be added dynamically/programatically. Overview is just the first tab - a template for each tab (reflecting the fetched items) is being implemented when the buttons work. For now, I'm just adding a test button to the collection, but as stated, this won't show. What am I missing?

I have a Overview.xaml file:

```
<UserControl // attributes omitted to save spaces... ask if needed>

<StackPanel>
    <Border>
        <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                   TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}">
            Welcome to Greenhouse App
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceButtons}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmodel:DeviceButton}">
                <Button Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10 10 0 0" Command="{Binding OpenTab}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding DeviceType}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    // Manually added test button...
    <Button x:Name="windMill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="50"
            Command="{Binding OpenTab}" FontFamily="Segoe Ui"
            Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="/Greenhouse;component/Icons/Windmill.png" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button
</StackPanel>
```

I'm trying to add an ObservableCollection of type DeviceButton, the _deviceButtons collection (Binded as ItemsSource to the ItemsControl)

The tabList items are working just find, and I can manually add more if needed (these will later be added through the OpenNewTab-command, which should be bound to the buttons)

The DeviceButton file:

```
public class DeviceButton
{
    private readonly string _content;
    private readonly string _deviceType;
    private readonly string _imageUrl;

    public DeviceButton(string content, string deviceType, string imageUrl)
    {
        _content = content;
        _deviceType = deviceType;
        _imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
    }

    public string DeviceType
    {
        get { return _deviceType; }
    }

    public string ImageUrl
    {
        get { return _imageUrl; }
    }
}
```

The collection is located in a viewmodel file, MainWindowViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand OpenTab { get; set; }

    private string tabControl { get; set; } = "0";
    private IInterTabClient _interTabClient;
    private ObservableCollection<TabContent> _tabContents = new ObservableCollection<TabContent>();
    private ObservableCollection<DeviceButton> _deviceButtons = new ObservableCollection<DeviceButton>();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _interTabClient = new MyInterTabClient();

        DeviceButtons.Add(new DeviceButton("Windturbine", "windturbine", "/Greenhouse;component/Icons/Windmill.png"));

        TabContents.Add(new TabContent("Overview", new Overview()));

        OpenTab = new RelayCommand<object>(OpenNewTab);
    }

    private void OpenNewTab(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Yo"); // Not yet implemented
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => tabControl);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<TabContent> TabContents
    {
        get { return _tabContents; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DeviceButton> DeviceButtons
    {
        get { return _deviceButtons; }
    }

    public IInterTabClient InterTabClient
    {
        get { return _interTabClient; }
    }
}
```

The buttons aren't loaded when I start the program (only the "test" button added manually in the WPF).

The UserControl, Overview, is considered a tab in another Controls.Metrowindow, MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dragablz:TabablzControl}">
        <Setter Property="CustomHeaderItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:TabContent}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:TabContent}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="4" Content="{Binding Content}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<dragablz:TabablzControl SelectedIndex="{Binding tabControl}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabContents}" x:Name="InitialTabablzControl" Margin="4 0 4 4">
    <dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
        <dragablz:InterTabController InterTabClient="{Binding MyInterTabClient}" />
    </dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
</dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

I guess it's an issue with the resources/binding in the Overview.xaml, but I've exhausted all suggested solutions I could find.

Comment: I would suggest using a tool like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to verify your DataContext is what you expect... I suspect the `DataContext` is being set to a `TabContent` object, which does not have a `DeviceButtons` property.

Comment: Did you try ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.TabContents, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"? And yes, you should use Snoop in such cases.

Comment: @galakt Thanks, that did it. If you do make an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Rachel Thanks, it's a really nifty tool, something I actually had been looking for.

Comment: @user2832479 Sure answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was in binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.TabContents, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=1, 
              AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
```

Comment: Just a minor remark: I used `DataContext.DeviceButtons` instead of `TabContents`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the `DataContext` is being set to a `TabContent` object, which does not have a `DeviceButtons` property

I would suggest using a tool like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to verify your `DataContext` is what you expect.

Comment: I've given you an up-vote, but my votes aren't public as my own reputation isn't high enough, yet.